# Extra Info being injected into an email over SMTP

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, go, smtp, amazon-ses

I've been having a really strange problem. I have a golang server, and I'm using net/smtp to send out emails. It was going well until we realized some extra information was being injected into emails, and that yahoo started ignoring our emails. Anyways, the information that gets sent out for the body of our info is:

```
From: test@withheld.com
To: me@gmail.com
Subject: Testing
MIME-version: 1.0;
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";
<html>
     <b> Testing </b>
</html>
```

That then gets sent to Amazon SES, the account we used to send emails is hosted on godaddy.
When the email arrives, and I show the original message body using gmail, I get this:

```
From: test@withheld.com
To: me@gmail.com
Subject: Testing
MIME-version: 1.0;
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8";

<html>
    <b> Testing </b>
</html>
Date: Wed, 29 Oct 2014 11:00:56 +0000
Message-ID: <[Lots of Numbers]@email.amazonses.com>
X-SES-Outgoing: [Some Numbers]
Feedback-ID: us-east-1.[numbers]=:AmazonSES
```

So those 4 additional fields get tacked on to our message bodies, which I presume would lead to us getting mark as spam or worse (yahoo is brutal.) Does anyone know where these 4 lines could have been added on? Definitely seems like SES, but I trust Godaddy a whole lot less.

(There were points where we had different spacing in our bodies, and the information would then inject into random locations in the message bodies)

Comment: Yep, other servers handle your e-mail and add headers that recipient servers might use to determine your reputation. Establishing an e-mail reputation takes a while, and involves both your IP and your domain; to start out, it might help to send mail mainly to active users, or just be extra vigilant about not sending unwanted mail (require folks to verify e-mail when setting up an account). You could A/B test SES against other e-mail sending services like SendGrid (search the Web for other options) to see who can best get you started.

Comment: The most likely explanation for all of this is that SES is trying to add *headers*, but your messages are not built quite according to spec and SES fails to correctly find the boundary between headers and body.  The fact that you aren't even adding a date suggests that your email is hand-rolled, not the best idea.

Comment: You do need a blank line after your headers, if the first snippet really is exactly how your message was sent. [`mime`](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/) and [`mime/multipart`](http://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) could help.

Comment: Thanks guys, I love the A/B test idea. Thanks for noting that that empty line appears from nowhere, the first entry was correct.

Comment: twotwo, do you know how to add the date or message-id using golang, net/smtp? I don't want to hand-roll an emailing service, as Michael said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a newline (`\r\n`) between the header and the body.

Also if you want an easy way to send emails in Go you can use [Gomail](https://github.com/go-gomail/gomail) (I'm the author):

```
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", "test@withheld.com")
    m.SetHeader("To", "me@gmail.com")
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Testing")
    m.SetBody("text/html", `<html>
     <b> Testing </b>
</html>`)

    d := gomail.NewPlainDialer("smtp.example.com", 587, "user", "123456")
    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you author of Gomail, I'll give it a test run!

Comment: I love the library. The only thing is it's 1.3 dependent because of   the quotedprintable library. I'll post back if I figure it out

Comment: Hey Ale, everything worked in 1.3, however you need to update your library for 1.4, as far as I can tell the package name "internal" is now used by go, so you'll need to change it from internal

Comment: This is on purpose as the quotedprintable package might enter the standard library.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a \r\n between headers and the body. You are also missing a date and a message-ID header. Lots of spam filters will take missing those as a good sign of sloppy spam/virus mail. The same for not having a text-only alternate.

Sendgrid or mandrill might help get these things right by default.

Comment: I highly recommend using Ale's library below, it's action packed, easy to set up, and works like a charm

Comment: SMTP MTAs automatically add a `MessageId` header if it's missing. Amazon SES even overwrites an existing `MessageId` AFAIK.

Comment: That depends on the MTA.

Comment: @UdoG yep, can confirm AWS SES overwrites the message id (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=262855)